# how to create regular expression in php for all input tags in a webpage?

Tags: php, regex

plz help me in making regular expressions with explaination of each components.i want to parse all input tags and text areatags given below-

```
<input id="t_15_k_5" type="text" value="Xxychf" name="t_15_k_5" style="display: none;"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="sn2sms" name="i_m" style="display: none;"></input>
<input id="kriya" type="hidden" value="sa65sdf656fdfd" name="kriya"></input>
<textarea id="m_15_b" name="m_15_b" style="display: none;">mwLCqRzP</textarea>
```

also this one -

```
<input id="mwLCqRzP" class="wickEnabled input" type="text" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Mobile Number';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Mobile Number') this.value='';" value="Mobile Number" onchange="javascript:dispLocMob(this);" onkeydown="javascript:dispLocMob(this);" onkeyup="javascript:dispLocMob(this);" maxlength="10" name="mwLCqRzP"></input>
```

i have written this code but not working-

```
preg_match_all("~<textarea(?=[^>]* name=[\"']([^'\"]*)|)(\s+[^>]*)?>(.*?)</textarea>~",$content,$textAreaResults)

preg_match_all('/<input(?=[^>]* name=["\']([^\'"]*)|)(?=[^>]* value=["\']([^\'"]*)|)/',$content,$results);
```

plz help.

Comment: Mixing regex with html is always bad idea. Use xml parser instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Parser

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

for example

if you have to use regex, the regex for each is

The actual regex for each is

`<input\b[^>]*>(.*?)</input>`

`<textarea\b[^>]*>(.*?)</textarea>`

note: the regex above will not match nested tags, Which in your case isnt an issue